# Why is "ge-"+past sometimes wrong as passive?

Tags: passive

If I cut (schneiden) my hair, it's geschnitten.

If I color (färben) it, it's gefärbt.

If I trim (stutzen) it, it's gestutzt.

But if I razor (rasieren or abrasieren) it, it's not gerasiert or geabrasiert. It's rasiert or abrasiert.

Comment: Just a guess, but "rasieren" comes from a foreign word, while all the other verbs were "always" German.

Comment: Partizip II von Verben, die auf "-ieren" enden, wird ohne "ge-" gebildet.

Comment: @Landei There are many verbs that have been imported into German rather recently and still take a "ge-" prefix. Some examples: killen – gekillt, dealen – gedealt, mobben  – gemobbt, scannen – gescannt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a general question on how the **Partizip II** is formed in German. This participle is used for the perfect tenses and all passive voices.

The general rule is, the *Partizip II* resembles first person past tense prefixed with *ge-* and without the final *-e*:

> färben: ich färbe, ich **färbt**e, ge**färbt**
>
> stutzen: ich stutze, ich **stutzt**e, ge**stutzt**
>
> legen: ich lege, ich **legt**e, ge**legt**

But sometimes, there are exceptions! The first is about strong verbs, here *-en* is added and there's often another vowel shift:

> schneiden: ich schneide, ich **schnitt**, ge**schnitt**en
>
> waschen: ich wasche, ich **wusch**, ge**wasch**en
>
> biegen: ich biege, ich **bog**, ge**bog**en
>
> liegen: ich liege, ich **lag**, ge**leg**en
>
> lügen: ich lüge, ich **log**, ge**log**en

The second is about verbs with inseparable prefixes. They don't get a *ge-* prefix but keep their original one, while the above two stem classes still apply:

> belegen: ich belege, ich **belegt**e, **belegt**
>
> verbiegen: ich verbiege, ich **verbog**, **verbog**en

The third is about verbs with separable prefixes. They get a *-ge-* between the original prefix and the stem. Again, the two stem classes still apply:

> abwaschen: ich wasche ab, ich **wusch ab**, **ab**ge**wasch**en
>
> weglegen: ich lege weg, ich **legt**e **weg**, **weg**ge**legt**

Unfortunately, there are still some irregular cases, verbs on *-ieren* for example:

> rasieren: ich rasiere, ich **rasiert**e, **rasiert**
>
> lackieren: ich lackiere, ich **lackiert**e, **lackiert**
>
> musizieren: ich musiziere, ich **musiziert**e, **musiziert**

And of course, the prefix has to be kept intact:

> abrasieren: ich rasiere ab, ich **rasiert**e **ab**, **abrasiert**.

Comment: The reason seems to be that rasieren has its accent on the second syllable, so it's treated as if the ra- were a non-separable prefix.

Comment: @RHa In fact, other verbs without a prefix that are not stressed on the first syllable show the same behaviour, even if they do not end in "-ieren", e.g., "berlinern", "scharwenzeln", "trompeten", "salbadern"