# (etwas) wird (an jmdn.) übergeben oder übergegeben? Warum?

Tags: verb, preposition, grammatical-case, passive, conjugation

Das Verb »geben« macht mich ein bisschen verrückt. In der Vergangenheitsform sagt man:

> Ich habe ihm etwas **ge**geben
>   Die Versuche haben wir endlich auf**ge**geben.

Aber was ist mit »übergeben«?
Warum sagt man im Passiv oder Perfekt einfach »übergeben«?

> Die Sendung wird (wurde) direkt ans Briefzentrum übergeben.
>   Er hat seine Datei ans FA übergeben.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es sich um eine Präposition + Verb handelt, z.B:

*an / ab / ein / über / vor / aus / auf / weiter*, usw. + **geben**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es handelt sich um unterschiedliche Verben.

> geben – ich gebe, ich gab, gegeben
>
> aufgeben — ich gebe auf, ich gab auf, aufgegeben ← trennbare Vorsilbe
>
> übergeben — ich übergebe, ich übergab, übergeben ← nicht trennbare Vorsilbe

Ganz allgemein muss man das Partizip Perfekt auswendig lernen. Achtung: Manche Verben gibt es in trennbarer und nicht trennbarer Form, und einige wenige haben sogar *in beiden Formen zwei verschiedene* Perfekt-Partizipien, die alle etwas unterschiedliches bedeuten.

Und leider gibt es oft auch Präposition und abgetrennte Vorsilbe im selben Satz:

> Ich **gebe** auf dem Postamt ein Paket **auf**.

Das **auf** am Ende ist die abgetrennte Vorsilbe des Verbs *aufgeben*, während das andere *auf* eine Preposition ist.

---

Also, see my answer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44727/why-is-ge-past-sometimes-wrong-as-passive).

Comment: Kann man zusätzlich nicht als Regel formulieren, dass das Partizip bei nichttrennbaren Vorsilben ohne "-ge" gebildet wird? Ich sehe jedenfalls kein Gegenbeispiel.

Comment: Guck dir mal meine Antwort auf die andere Frage an, die ist ziemlich komplett. Uwe hat im Kommentar dann noch weitere Endsilben ergänzt.

Comment: Das ist richtig, man muss eigentlich nicht das Partizip Perfekt auswendig lernen, sondern ob es sich um (1) ein nicht zusammengesetztes, (2) ein zusammengesetztes trennbares oder (3) ein zusammengesetztes nicht trennbares Verb handelt. Auswendig lernen muss man dann nur das Partizip Perfekt des nicht zusammengesetzten Verbs, sofern es unregelmäßig ist.

Comment: Du musst aber in jedem Fall noch die Vergangenheitsform auswendig lernen. Den Ablaut verrät dir leider keiner. Und den zweiten Ablaut des Partizips leider auch nicht.

Comment: Wenn ich es richtig verstehe, es gibt keine "ge-" nur wenn das Verb nicht trennbares ist. Was ist in dem Fall mit "ich übernehme die Kosten" u. "ich habe die Kosten übergenommen" (die Kosten werden übergenommen)? "Übernehmen" ist nicht trennbares Verb, oder? Oder ist über**ge**nommen auch falsch?

Comment: *Übernehmen* ist nicht trennbar. Nicht trennbare Verben behalten ihr eigenes Prefix. Es wird kein -ge- eingefügt. Daher lautet das Partizip Perfekt **übernommen**.

Comment: Bitte schau dir auch meine Antwort auf die andere Frage an. Sie ist ziemlich komplett.

Comment: Es gibt auch Verben mit trennbarer und untrennbarer Vorsilbe, die teilweise gleich aussehen, aber deutlich unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben - im gesprochenen Wort sind sie an der Betonung unterschiedlicher Silben erkennbar. Beispiel: Man fährt mit dem Auto, und da steht plötzlich ein Mann auf der Straße. Man kann den Mann **um**fahren oder ihn um**fahren** - letzteres ist die korrekte Vorgehensweise, während erstere für den Mann böse körperliche und für den Fahrer böse juristische Folgen hätte.